# php-sodium on Amazon Linux 2023

Tags: php, libsodium, amazon-linux, sodium, amazon-linux-extras

php-sodium is absent on Amazon Linux 2023 and can't be easilly installed. So I'll put the solution here as an answer.

Expected to install php-sodium/libsodium on Amazon Linux 2023, but there is no the simple way, because amazon-linux-extras not included as well

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo yum install php8.1-devel php-pear gcc
wget https://download.libsodium.org/libsodium/releases/LATEST.tar.gz
// verify the file integrity https://libsodium.gitbook.io/doc/installation#integrity-checking
tar -xvzf LATEST.tar.gz
cd libsodium-stable
./configure
make && make check
sudo make install
sudo pecl install -f libsodium
//add extension=sodium.so to php.ini
```

Found this solution on https://github.com/amazonlinux/amazon-linux-2023/issues/204

Thanks https://github.com/ArronKing for answering